# How to check if multiple items are selected in a pivot table?

Tags: vba, excel, pivot

Is it possible to know which items are checked in a PivotTable filter in case `MultipleItems` are allowed?

I only see `.Visible` property to check it but it only works if multiple items are not allowed.
If multiple items are allowed and checked `.Visible` property, you only see "ALL" instead of all items selected.

Any way to do it?

```
Dim pvt As PivotTable
Dim fld As PivotField
Dim itm As PivotItem
Dim flt As PivotFilter

Dim i As Integer


Set xbFuente = ThisWorkbook
Set xlDatos = xbFuente.Worksheets("TABLAS")
Set pvt = xlDatos.PivotTables("MAIN")

pvt.ManualUpdate = True
Application.EnableEvents = False
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

If pvt.ShowPageMultipleItemLabel = True Then
   Debug.Print "The words 'Multiple Items' can be displayed."
End If

For Each fld In pvt.PageFields        
    Debug.Print fld.Name & " -- " & fld.Orientation & " -- " & fld.EnableItemSelection & " -- " & fld.EnableMultiplePageItems & " -- "


    If fld.AllItemsVisible = True Then
    ' If all items are visible  "ALL"
        For Each itm In fld.VisibleItems
            Debug.Print "---- ALLITEMSVISIBLE TRUE --" & "VISIBLE" & " -- " & itm.Name & " -- " & itm.Visible
        Next
    Else
        For Each itm In fld.VisibleItems
            Debug.Print "---- ALLITEMSVISIBLE FALSE --" & "VISIBLE" & itm.Name & " -- " & itm.Visible
        Next
        For Each itm In fld.HiddenItems
            Debug.Print "--------ALLITEMSVISIBLE FALSE --" & "HIDDEN -- " & itm.Name & " -- " & itm.Visible
        Next
        For Each itm In fld.PivotItems
            Debug.Print "--------ALLITEMSVISIBLE FALSE --" & "HIDDEN -- " & itm.Name & " -- " & itm.Value
        Next
    End If

    Next
```

**Result**:
`Warranty Flag -- 3 -- Verdadero -- Verdadero -- 
---- ALLITEMSVISIBLE FALSE --VISIBLE(All) -- Verdadero
--------ALLITEMSVISIBLE FALSE --HIDDEN -- A -- Falso
--------ALLITEMSVISIBLE FALSE --HIDDEN -- I -- Falso
--------ALLITEMSVISIBLE FALSE --HIDDEN -- O -- Falso
--------ALLITEMSVISIBLE FALSE --HIDDEN -- P -- Falso`

Answer (score 1):

Try the sample code below:

```
Sub Check_PivotFilter_Selection()

Dim pvt As PivotTable
Dim fld As PivotField
Dim itm As PivotItem
Dim flt As PivotFilter

Dim i As Integer

Set xbFuente = ThisWorkbook
Set xlDatos = xbFuente.Worksheets("TABLAS")
Set pvt = xlDatos.PivotTables("MAIN")

pvt.ManualUpdate = True
Application.EnableEvents = False
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

If pvt.ShowPageMultipleItemLabel = True Then
   Debug.Print "The words 'Multiple Items' can be displayed."
End If


For Each fld In pvt.PageFields
    Debug.Print fld.Name & " -- " & fld.Orientation & " -- " & fld.EnableItemSelection & " -- " & fld.EnableMultiplePageItems & " -- "

    ' loop through all items in Field, and check which ones are Selected (and which ones are not)
    For Each itm In fld.PivotItems

        If itm.Visible = True Then
            Debug.Print " Item " & itm.Name & " in Field " & fld.Name & " is Visible (Selected) "
        Else
            Debug.Print " Item " & itm.Name & " in Field " & fld.Name & " is Hidden (Not Selected) "
        End If

    Next itm    
Next fld

End Sub
```

Comment: I get false for every item even though the item is checked

Answer (score 0):

i check your code and i have same result as mine. In my tests last week i tried with .hidden & .visible properties and it works fine if i do not select "multiple items selected".

```
Warranty Flag -- 3 -- Verdadero -- Verdadero -- 
Item I in Field Warranty Flag is Hidden (Not Selected) 
Item O in Field Warranty Flag is Hidden (Not Selected) 
Item IW in Field Warranty Flag is Hidden (Not Selected)
```

Pivot table was created manually, not created by vba and i am working with excel 2010.