# How to list pivot fields from a pivot table?

Tags: excel, vba, pivot-table

I have a workbook with many worksheets, each having multiple pivot tables. I wrote a code to list all of the PT's and their source data:

```
Dim St As Worksheet
Dim NewSt As Worksheet
Dim pt As PivotTable
Dim I, K As Long
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Set NewSt = Worksheets.Add
I = 1: K = 2
With NewSt
    .Cells(I, 1) = "Name"
    .Cells(I, 2) = "Source"
    .Cells(I, 3) = "Location"
    For Each St In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
        For Each pt In St.PivotTables
            I = I + 1
            .Cells(I, 1).Value = pt.Name
            .Cells(I, 2).Value = pt.SourceData
            .Cells(I, 3).Value = pt.TableRange1.Address
        Next
    Next
    .Activate
End With
```

The result will look like this in a new active worksheet in my file:
[image: Result Table]

But, in all my pivot tables, i have filtered "Apr", "May" from the columns labels as shown by arrows. [image: Notice the black arrow]
I would like to show the fields "Finance Budget 2020", "Feb RPM" and "Jan RPM" using my code above. How can i do that?

Comment: Show the fields where?  In the pivot tables, or in your report sheet?

Comment: @TimWilliams in my report sheet.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39884591/how-to-check-if-multiple-items-are-selected-in-a-pivot-table